# how to open a new tab using context menu in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]I am using a datatable to show some data and using context menu to navigate to another page from the datatable.But the problem is that when i am clicking the context menu tab the new window is opening in the same tab.but i need to open it in another tab,but it is not happening.I am giving the code ..

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="showcase">
            $(function() {
                var selectedVal;
                $.contextMenu({
                    selector : '.context-menu-one',
                    callback : function(key, options) {
                        var row = options.$trigger;
                        var newUrl = key;

                        if (key === 'calllist.do') {
                            var rows = row.find("td").eq(2).html();
                            actionUrl = '?' + 'a_no='
                                    + rows.toLocaleString();
                        }
                        if (key === 'travel') {
                            var rows = row.find("td").eq(3).html();
                            actionUrl = '?' + 'a_no='
                                    + rows.toLocaleString();
                        }
                        if (key === 'call_usage') {
                            var rows = row.find("td").eq(3).html();
                            actionUrl = '?' + 'a_no='
                                    + rows.toLocaleString();
                        }
                        if (key === 'network_analysis') {
                            var rows = row.find("td").eq(3).html();
                            actionUrl = '?' + 'a_no='
                                    + rows.toLocaleString();
                        }
                        if (key === 'location_analysis.do') {
                            var rows = row.find("td").eq(3).html();
                            actionUrl = '?' + 'a_no='
                                    + rows.toLocaleString();
                        }

                        if (key === 'location_tracker.do') {
                            var rows = row.find("td").eq(3).html();
                            actionUrl = '?' + 'a_no='
                                    + rows.toLocaleString();
                        }

                        if (key === 'personal') {
                            var rows = row.find("td").eq(1).html();
                            actionUrl = '?' + 'a_no='
                                    + rows.toLocaleString();
                            //  alert(actionUrl);

                        }

                        if (key === 'newsim.do') {
                            var rows = row.find("td").eq(5).html();
                            actionUrl = '?' + 'a_no='
                                    + rows.toLocaleString();
                            //  alert(actionUrl);

                        }

                        if (key === 'analyzecallingno') {
                            var rows = row.find("td").eq(2).html();
                            actionUrl = '?' + 'a_no='
                                    + rows.toLocaleString();


                        }

                        if (key === 'simdensity.do') {
                            var rows = row.find("td").eq(5).html();
                            actionUrl = '?' + 'a_no='
                                    + rows.toLocaleString();


                        }

                        document.forms[0].action = newUrl + actionUrl;
                        document.forms[0].submit();
                    },
                    items : {

                        "analyzecallingno" : {
                            name : "Analyze Calling Number"
                        },
                        "travel": {
                            name : "Analyze Caller Tower"
                        },
                        "network_analysis" : {
                            name : "Social Network Analysis"
                        },
                        "call_usage" : {
                            name : "Call Analysis Summary"
                        },
                        "location_tracker.do" : {
                            name : "Location Tracking"
                        },
                        "personal" : {
                            name : "Caller Personal Details"
                        }

                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

        <table class="tableData context-menu-one" id="tableData"
            style="overflow-x: scroll">
            <thead>
                <tr style="font-size: 14px;">
                    <th align="left">CALLTYPE</th>
                    <th align="left">CALLER</th>
                    <th align="left">CALLEE</th>
                    <th align="left">DURATION</th>
                    <th align="left">START DATE</th>
                    <th align="left">END DATE</th>
                    <th align="left">FROM LOC</th>
                    <th align="left">TO LOC</th>
                    <th align="left">IMEI</th>
                    <th align="left">IMSI</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${searchpage}" var="listofvalues">
                    <tr class="context-menu-one notfirst" style="font-size: 12px;">
                        <td align="left"><c:out value="${listofvalues.call_type}" /></td>
                        <td align="left"><c:out value="${listofvalues.a_no}" /></td>
                        <td align="left"><c:out value="${listofvalues.b_no}" /></td>
                        <td align="left"><c:out
                                value="${listofvalues.call_duration}" /></td>
                        <td align="left"><c:out value="${listofvalues.start_day}" /></td>
                        <td align="left"><c:out value="${listofvalues.end_day}" /></td>
                        <td align="left"><c:out
                                value="${listofvalues.a_home_circle}" /></td>
                        <td align="left"><c:out
                                value="${listofvalues.a_rome_circle}" /></td>
                        <td align="left"><c:out value="${listofvalues.a_imei}" /></td>
                        <td align="left"><c:out value="${listofvalues.a_imsi}" /></td>

                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: i know that in HTML a lint to open new tab look linke this <A HREF="http://www.kopfchaos.ch" TARGET="_blank">Link zu kopfchaos.ch</A> probarty you can use it

Comment: where i should implement that in here??

Comment: is the if i see it right your context ar aktuly a text an not a link or?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something like `$("form:first").attr('target', '_blank').submit();` instead of `document.forms[0].action = newUrl + actionUrl;`.

ps. don't forget to set your action URL:

```
$("form:first").attr({
                      'target':'_blank',
                      'action':newUrl + actionUrl
                    }).submit();
```

You could also use `$( "form" ).first().attr....`.

Comment: i did that but not working even the page navigation is stoped

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check it out and open your console to see if you get any error message.

Comment: yah its working but there is a problem it is opening a new window in the browser but i need it in my dashboard

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you have an example?

Comment: why it is opening a new window in the browser can you tell please ??

Comment: Because of the `target: _blank`. See http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_target.asp for more information(I know I may not refer to W3, but it was the first hit this time hehe).

Comment: what i have to do to remain in the same window??

Comment: Do you mean some kind of popup? If you use `_blank` it will open in a new tab. Which browser are you using?

Comment: did you see the screen shot i posted ??when i click on a menu it will open a tab in the yellow tab

Comment: Did you code the table with context menu and the whole other JS by yourself or do you use any kind of framework?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48654/discussion-between-lucifer-and-guyt)